# Reading a file between specific indexes

Tags: python

Lets say I have a text file as follows:

test.txt:

```
abcabcabcabc
```

And I would like to make a string from the subset of the characters in the file from between index 3 to index 7, which would be the string "cabca".

How do I go about doing that? I know how to do it for a string but not for a file of characters.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects, use the `read` and `seek` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_string = open('test.txt').read()
```

then slice the string :)

or
as per @Grimmy comment

```
with file as open('test.txt'):
    your_string = file.read()
```

Comment: Maybe at least use a context manger for ``open``, so the file descriptor is properly closed. We don't know if there are multiple files involved here.

Comment: Isn't that an inefficient way of doing that? What if the file is thousands of characters long and I only need to check indexes that contain 10 characters?

Comment: @FlameDra I thought you said test.txt is a file as follows... abcabcabcabc?   Generally, you do have to read from a file in order to manipulate the data in that file. I don't know of any tricks to get around that.

Comment: @DanHall that was an example file. I am looking for the best way to do this, but what you suggested does work! Thanks!